# Android State Save

Tags: android

Its A Small Program i am trying to learn state in android but i dont know when i click on my button count increments but rotate the screen value doesnt get store i dont know whats wrong. It Succesffuly shows the toast that it entered but show count to be Zero.

```
package com.example.na462.layoutsample2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle; 
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
* Created by Na462 on 8/7/2017.
*/

public class States extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
TextView textView ;
int Count  = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.states);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText("You Pressed: " + Count + "Times");
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Count++;
            textView.setText("You Pressed: " + Count + "Times");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putInt("Counter",Count);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Count = savedInstanceState.getInt("Counter");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Count is: " + Count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textView.setText("You Pressed: " + Count + "Times");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use this version of `onSaveInstanceState` (without `PersistableBundle` parameter) as you are using the verison of `onRestoreInstanceState` without that parameter:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

Comment: If it's working, would you please upvote and accept the answer?